# Writing Unicode from R to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, r, unicode

I'm trying to write Unicode strings from R to SQL, and then use that SQL table to power a Power BI dashboard. Unfortunately, the Unicode characters only seem to work when I load the table back into R, and not when I view the table in SSMS or Power BI.

```
require(odbc)
require(DBI)
require(dplyr)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      .connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=R9-0KY02L01\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test;trusted_connection=yes;")
testData <- data_frame(Characters = "❤")
dbWriteTable(con,"TestUnicode",testData,overwrite=TRUE)
result <- dbReadTable(con, "TestUnicode")
result$Characters
```

Successfully yields:

```
> result$Characters
[1] "❤"
```

However, when I pull that table in SSMS:

```
SELECT * FROM TestUnicode
```

I get two different characters:

```
Characters
~~~~~~~~~~
â¤
```

Those characters are also what appear in Power BI. How do I correctly pull the heart character outside of R?

Comment: Did you try _result as text_ in SSMS?

Comment: Yes, the same issue happens when I save results as text.

Answer (score 14):

It turns out this is a bug somewhere in R/DBI/the ODBC driver. The issue is that R stores strings as UTF-8 encoded, while SQL Server stores them as UTF-16LE encoded. Also, when dbWriteTable creates a table, it by default creates a VARCHAR column for strings which can't even hold Unicode characters. Thus, you need to both:

1. Change the column in the R data frame from being a string column to a list column of UTF-16LE raw bytes.
2. When using dbWriteTable, specify the field type as being NVARCHAR(MAX)

This seems like something that should still be handled by either DBI or ODBC or something though.

```
require(odbc)
require(DBI)

# This function takes a string vector and turns it into a list of raw UTF-16LE bytes. 
# These will be needed to load into SQL Server
convertToUTF16 <- function(s){
  lapply(s, function(x) unlist(iconv(x,from="UTF-8",to="UTF-16LE",toRaw=TRUE)))
}

# create a connection to a sql table
connectionString <- "[YOUR CONNECTION STRING]"
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      .connection_string = connectionString)

# our example data
testData <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), Char = c("I", "❤","Apples"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# we adjust the column with the UTF-8 strings to instead be a list column of UTF-16LE bytes
testData$Char <- convertToUTF16(testData$Char)

# write the table to the database, specifying the field type
dbWriteTable(con, 
             "UnicodeExample", 
             testData, 
             append=TRUE, 
             field.types = c(Char = "NVARCHAR(MAX)"))

dbDisconnect(con)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48174882/10489562) and [github: r-dbi/DBI#215: Storing unicode characters in SQL Server](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/issues/215)

Following  `field.types = c(Char = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")`   but with vector and compute of max because of the error [dbReadTable/dbGetQuery returns Invalid Descriptor Index ....](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/112) :

```
vector_nvarchar<-c(Filter(Negate(is.null), 
                              (
                                lapply(testData,function(x){
                                  if (is.character(x) ) c(
                                    names(x),
                                    paste0("NVARCHAR(", 
                                           max(
                                             # nvarchar(max) gave error dbReadTable/dbGetQuery returns Invalid Descriptor Index error on SQL server 
                                             # https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/112  
                                             # so we compute the max                                           
                                             nchar(
                                               iconv( #nchar doesn't work for UTF-8 :  help (nchar)
                                                 Filter(Negate(is.null),x)
                                                 ,"UTF-8","ASCII",sub ="x" 
                                               )
                                             )
                                             ,na.rm = TRUE)
                                           ,")"
                                    )
                                  )
                                })
                              )
    ))

con= DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),.connection_string=xxxxt, encoding = 'UTF-8')

DBI::dbWriteTable(con,"UnicodeExample",testData, overwrite= TRUE, append=FALSE, field.types= vector_nvarchar)

 DBI::dbGetQuery(con,iconv('select * from UnicodeExample'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the last answer I also tried to find an automated way for writing data frames to SQL server. I can not confirm the nvarchar(max) errors, so I ended up with these functions:

```
convertToUTF16_df <- function(df){
  output <- cbind(df[sapply(df, typeof) != "character"]
    , list.cbind(apply(df[sapply(df, typeof) == "character"], 2, function(x){
      return(lapply(x, function(y) unlist(iconv(y, from = "UTF-8", to = "UTF-16LE", toRaw = TRUE))))
    }))

  )[colnames(df)]

  return(output)
}

field_types <- function(df){

  output <- list()
  output[colnames(df)[sapply(df, typeof) == "character"]] <- "nvarchar(max)"

  return(output)
}

DBI::dbWriteTable(odbc_connect
                  , name = SQL("database.schema.table")
                  , value = convertToUTF16_df(df)
                  , overwrite = TRUE
                  , row.names = FALSE
                  , field.types = field_types(df)
)
```

Comment: setting all the character columns to varchar(max) avoids having to create the table manually or changing individual column length in dbWriteTable. Was exactly what i looking for

Answer (score 0):

I found the previous answer very useful but ran into problems with character vectors that had another encoding such as 'latin1' instead of UTF-8. This resulted in random NULLs in the database column due to special characters such as non-breaking spaces.

In order to avoid these encoding issues, I've made the following modifications to detect the character vector encoding or otherwise default back to UTF-8 before conversion to UTF-16LE:

```
library(rlist)

convertToUTF16_df <- function(df){
  output <- cbind(df[sapply(df, typeof) != "character"]
                  , list.cbind(apply(df[sapply(df, typeof) == "character"], 2, function(x){
                    return(lapply(x, function(y) {
                        if (Encoding(y)=="unknown") {
                          unlist(iconv(enc2utf8(y), from = "UTF-8", to = "UTF-16LE", toRaw = TRUE))
                        } else {
                          unlist(iconv(y, from = Encoding(y), to = "UTF-16LE", toRaw = TRUE))
                        }
                      }))
                  }))
  )[colnames(df)]

  return(output)
}

field_types <- function(df){

  output <- list()
  output[colnames(df)[sapply(df, typeof) == "character"]] <- "nvarchar(max)"

  return(output)
}

DBI::dbWriteTable(odbc_connect
                  , name = SQL("database.schema.table")
                  , value = convertToUTF16_df(df)
                  , overwrite = TRUE
                  , row.names = FALSE
                  , field.types = field_types(df)
)
```

Ideally, I'd still modify this to remove the rlist dependency but it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the package RODBC instead of odbc/DBI. I've have used RODBC with SQL Server and with Microsoft Access as permanent data storage system. I never had trouble with german umlaut (e.g. Ä, ä, ..., ß)
I wonder if using iconv is an appealing alternative as there seem to boe some '\X00' issues (e.g. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2010/06/more-powerful-iconv-in-r/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31154043)

Comment: Sorry,  I do not understand what's wrong with my answer. I have faced a similar problem with DBI/odbc. I've read  the best rated answer which requires changing souce code and use list processing with iconv and "raw" bytes. I could fix my problem switching to the ROBC package instead. Surely it also required changing the source code, but for me this alternitive seemed to be more attractive

Comment: @Rolf: I don't remember the details, but when I first connect my first R application to SQL server I had lot of problems of stability and disconnection with RODBC until I decided to use DBI. And after everything was going fine. Even if your last comment is a good news, I won't go back to RODBC. Even if I use pure SQL built  by myself in a function instead of `dbWriteTable()` and or `dbAppendTable()` for my old version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer as an Extension to the top answer, because some people might find it useful.

If you need Unicode strings in SQL statements such as `INSERT` or `UPDATE` where you cannot use `dbWriteTable()`, you can constructing your query with `dbBind()` like this:

```
x <- "äöü"
x <- iconv(x, from="UTF-8", to="UTF-16LE", toRaw = TRUE)

q <- 
  "
    update foobar
    set umlauts = ?
    where id = 1
  ")

query <- DBI::dbSendStatement(con, q)
DBI::dbBind(query, list(x))
DBI::dbClearResult(query)
```