# R & SQL Server - dbWriteTable character encoding - issues with German "Umlaute"

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I try to write data from R to my SQL Server Database (2016 Version), but I have problems with German Umlaute (ä, ü, ö, ß and so on).

Database: Latin1_General_CI_AS

R: Latin

Writing my R data frames to the database works absolutely fine using this code:

```
    DBI::dbWriteTable(odbc_con
                  , name = SQL("database.schema.table")
                  , value = dataframe
                  , overwrite = TRUE
                  , row.names = FALSE
)
```

I also get the correct Umlaute back when I use this code:

```
dataframe <- dbGetQuery(odbc_con, "SELECT * FROM database.schema.table")
```

BUT:
When I query the data outside R (SQL Server Management Studio, Denodo, Tableau) I do not get the correct Umlaute.

I also checked if the database is the problem here, but when I create a table containing Umlaute directly on the database there are no issues. Every query returns the correct Umlaute and also SQL Server Management Studio displays them in the right way.

What is wrong with my `dbWriteTable` code?

Please let me know if you need further information about system / software to help me on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105277/writing-unicode-from-r-to-sql-server